# IndexOutOfRangeException when button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making a simple shopping cart. which adds product to the shopping cart page from a button which is at another page my add to cart button is as follows

```
 protected void addCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["mySC"] == null)
            {
                mySC = new CartClass();
                Session["mySC"] = mySC;

            }

            string ID = Request.QueryString["ID"];
            mySC = (CartClass)Session["mySC"];
            DataTable dt = DA.selectQuery("Select * from Trees where ID='"+ID+"'");
            DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
                mySC.insert(new cartItems(Int32.Parse(ID),
                    row["TreeName"].ToString(),
                    row["Image"].ToString(),
                    Double.Parse(row["PricePerCube"].ToString()), 1));


        }
    }
```

when this button is being clicked the following error pops up

An exception of type `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` occurred in `System.Data.dll` but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There is no row at position 0.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: **SQL Injection Alert!** Do not use string concatenation for building SQL queries. Especially, when you directly read `QueryString["ID"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
```

Will throw exception if no rows returned. Add an if condition before it

```
If (dt.Rows.Count > 0){

DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
            mySC.insert(new   cartItems(Int32.Parse(ID),
                row["TreeName"].ToString(),
                row["Image"].ToString(),
                    Double.Parse(row["PricePerCube"].ToString()), 1));



}
```

Comment: the button does not give error anymore but when I click on my cart page to check if the item is added or not it gives me this error

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'gv'.  Remove one definition.

gv is the gridview that the data must be added to..

Comment: Please show up your code. Add gv.DataSourceId = null;  before defining Datasource